# How to get wifi channel width used by ap in UWP?

Tags: .net, wifi, uwp

I want to know my the channel width used by my ap (20MHz, 40MHz, 80MHz) using UWP. Sometimes channel width is described as multiple channel (3,4 for 40MHz or 3,4,5,6 for 80MHz)

I'm using [WiFiAvailableNetwork](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiavailablenetwork) and I can only get the first channel used. I cannot get the subsequent channel used or the channel width used.

Are there any function that I should be aware of?

Comment: You mean when code like `var availablenetworks = adapter.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks;` you can only get one available network? Can you please provide more details and your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, getting channel width is not supported in UWP. See http://www.matthafner.com/wifianalyzer/help/limitations